# Why does numpy's `np.char.encode` turn an empty unicode array into an empty `float64` array?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have an empty unicode array:

```
a = np.array([], dtype=np.str_)
```

I want to encode it:

```
b = np.char.encode(a, encoding='utf8')
```

Why is the result an empty array with `dtype=float64`?

```
# array([], dtype=float64)
```

If the array is not empty the resulting array is a properly encoded array with `dtype=|S[n]`:

```
a = np.array(['ss', 'ff☆'], dtype=np.str_)
b = np.char.encode(a, encoding='utf8')
# array([b'ss', b'ff\xe2\x98\x86'], dtype='|S5')
```

**EDIT:** The accepted answer below does, in fact, answer the question as posed but if you come here looking for a workaround, here is what I did:

```
if array.size == 0:
    encoded_array = np.chararray((0,))
else:
    encoded_array = np.char.encode(a, encoding='utf8')
```

This will produce an empty encoded array with `dtype='|S1'` if your decoded array is empty.

Comment: It could well be an oversight.  The `np.char` functions apply python string methods elementwise to the strings in the array.  `numpy` has little string code of its own.  It may be depending on the conversions to determine the dtype of the result, and without any it ends up returning a `np.zeros(0)` (or `np.empty(0)`), both of which have a `float` default dtype.  `np.char` functions are not heavily used, so edge cases like this could have escaped developer's attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source of `numpy.char.encode` is available [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/numpy/core/defchararray.py#L575-L608). It basically calls `_vec_string` which returns an empty array of type `np.object_` in this case. This result is provided to `_to_string_or_unicode_array` which builds the final array and determine its type. Its code is available [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/fe2bb380fd9a084b622ff3f00cb6f245e8c1a10e/numpy/core/defchararray.py#L62). It basically converts the Numpy array to a list so to then provide it to `np.asarray`. The goal of this operation is to determine the type of the array but the thing is that **empty arrays have a default type of `np.float64` by convention** (I think it is because Numpy was initially design for physicist who usually work with `np.float64` arrays). This result is quite unexpected in this context, but the `"S0"` does not exists and I am not sure everyone would agree that the `"S1"` type is better here (still, it is certainly better than `np.float64`). Feel free to [fill an issue on the GitHub Numpy repository](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues) so to start a discussion about this behaviour.

Comment: In fact, a NumPy issue about this already exists: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/13156